# How to organize Java-Project without packages?

Tags: java, information-hiding

I am working on a java-library and due to information-hiding, I was forced to move all my java-files into a single package in order to mark some of them as package private.

Is there any way to some how organize these java-files into "packages" without violating the information-hiding-principle?

Comment: If all your files are in the same package and all are package private, there is really no point to it, since it would be the same as if the were all public in the first place.

Comment: Not all are package private, but some. The problem is that these few package-private classes are required in the entire library, but are in the same way too dangerous to be kept public. There was no other option to put them into a single package.

Answer (score 1):

That is what Java 9 **modules** are for. They introduce an additional level of encapsulation.

```
private
package-private
module-private
public
```

`module-private` are public members in packages which are not exported.

In the following example, class `PublicClass` is in package `com.library`. In that same package, there is a `module-info.java` file which declares a Java module and exports packages which are public API. All classes in the packages which are not exported will not be visible from modules which depend on this one.

```
package com.library;

public class PublicClass {}
```

```
package com.library.internal;

public class InternalClass {}
```

```
module com.library {
    exports com.library;
}
```

```
module com.app {
    requires com.library;
}
```

```
package com.app;

class App {
    void run() {
        new InternalClass(); // compile-time error
        new PublicClass(); // success
    }
}
```